What keeps causing my decryption method to have a ValueError: Padding is Incorrect?
I'm currently working on a school project and I want to encrypt data from my typescript frontend to my django backend. I'm using AES to encrypt and decrypt data. I generated a random secret key and stored it in my .env file as such
SECRET='DfkCqKG7zAovGC/ZXdTG5SkW5rNP8AWU3FjW56xdKv4='

And In my frontend and backend I've added this code respectively:
Frontend:
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const SECRET_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET

export function encryptData(data: string): string {
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16); 
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(SECRET_KEY), { iv });
    const ivAndEncryptedData = iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext);
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(ivAndEncryptedData);
}

export function decryptData(encryptedData: string): string {
    const decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedData);
    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(decoded.words.slice(0, 4));  
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(decoded.words.slice(4)); 
    const cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ ciphertext, iv });
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(SECRET_KEY));
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}


Backend:
import os
import base64
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad, pad
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

SECRET_KEY = base64.b64decode(os.getenv('SECRET'))

def encryptData(data: str) -> str:
    cipher = AES.new(SECRET_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC)
    padded_data = pad(data.encode(), AES.block_size)  # Apply padding
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
    iv_and_ct = cipher.iv + ct_bytes
    return b64encode(iv_and_ct).decode('utf-8')

def decryptData(encrypted_data: str) -> str:
    encrypted_data_bytes = b64decode(encrypted_data)
    iv = encrypted_data_bytes[:16]  
    ct = encrypted_data_bytes[16:] 
    cipher = AES.new(SECRET_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    decrypted_padded_data = cipher.decrypt(ct)
    pt = unpad(decrypted_padded_data, AES.block_size)
    return pt.decode('utf-8')

Whenever I the data is encrypted in the frontend then sent to the backend it seems to crash at pt = unpad(decrypted_padded_data, AES.block_size) stating that ValueError: Padding is incorrect. I'm not really good with encryption/decryption and sadly, ChatGPT hasn't helped me solve the issue at all, let alone understand it.
I have tried changing my key multiple times thinking that it may be the issue but sadly that was no help at all. All I have done so far is log the data moving in between the front end and backend and all I could say for certain is that:

When the data is encrypted, assume X and Y, the encrypted data is sent correctly to the backend and there is no change.
I have logged the keys in both the frontend and backend and noticed in the frontend when I log the Secret key I get DfkCqKG7zAovGC/ZXdTG5SkW5rNP8AWU3FjW56xdKv4= but int he backend I get b'\n)\x02\xa8\xa1\xbb\xcc\n/\x18/\xcd]\xd4\xc6\xe5)\x16\xe6\xb3O\xf1e\x94\xdcX\xd6\xebl]+\x0e' and im not sure if thats an issue or what im meant to do to fix it if so.


You need to base64 decode the key in Javascript. Currently you're just UTF-8 encoding it.

iv is an array of 16 32-bit words -- 64 bytes.  You're only removing 16 bytes.  If you want 16 bytes, then use random(4).

@TimRoberts - iv is an array of 4 32-bit words, i.e. 16 bytes long. The parameter of random() specifies the number of bytes, not words (which is admittedly not necessarily intuitive).

You're right, I'm wrong.  I looked up the source.  The concept that one specifies a number of BYTES when creating a WORD array that consists of QWORDS is quite astounding, and is probably why Javascript programmers have issues.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I'm sorry i don't quite understand what you mean. If you are talking about the decryption method then I currently do not have an issue with it. i have an issue with the data being sent from the frontend to the backend then getting the error I mentioned in the post.

You're getting an error because you are using a different key in javascript frontend than you are using in the python backend. The reason the key is different was explained in my first comment, as was the fix.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you very much that worked! :)
